# Why was my answer deleted without me knowing about it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, specific-answer

I answered [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402420) yesterday but I noticed that my answer was deleted without my knowledge.

My answer was written 13 hours ago and both the question and my answer were deleted 10 hours ago. What is the reason of the deletion of my answer without even letting me know about it? would not it be more polite to at least let me know why my answer was deleted since I spent some time answering the question?

Comment: The asker deleted the thread. When that happens you can just flag the question (or something else, and explain what happened). Moderators will deal with it. You may take note of this piece of rudeness from the asker. Do take into account that noobs may do that out of ignorance.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the explanation. My understanding was that a question which already has an answer can not be deleted. Was I wrong?

Comment: The rule reads: A question with an *upvoted* answer cannot be deleted by the asker. A newbie may think that just saying "thanks" is enough. Most likely someone who hasn't paid attention /didn't think about it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks again.

Comment: Related: [Why do some users delete their questions after receiving an answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8528) and other posts [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/8528).

Comment: You can find in this post exact details on deletion: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)  It mentions that the OP can't delete delete their own question when if it
has an upvoted answer, or
has an accepted answer, or
has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes). (However, even a question which has an upvoted answer can still be deleted by other users based on votes to delete.)

Comment: This is yet another reminder that people should upvote answers that they believe should be immune from this sort of deletion.