# Immediate question deletion to prevent others from seeing an answer

Tags: discussion, etiquette, deleted-questions, policy

I recently answered a question about a simple strategy game.  (Mine was the only answer.)  The OP deleted the question about a minute later.  It occurs to me that he might not have wanted a potential opponent in this strategy game to see the answer.  Is this acceptable behavior?  If it is not, how does one report it?

Comment: [This?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2747014/11619) Undeleted.

Comment: Can't help to note that this is a really bad question, hence resisting the urge to answer it and voting to close instead, as the site recommends, would prevent such later unfortunate events.

Comment: It just got redeleted.....Rather frustrating.

Comment: See also: [Why do some users delete their questions after receiving an answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8528) (And other discussions [linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/8528).)

Comment: Reundeleted. The question is not great, but it is not for the OP to decide - you be the judge. I also made sure they won't redelete it for a little while.

Comment: "Rather frustrating" What? To see users answering questions that they should insta-delete, if only they took the rules of the site seriously? Yes, this is most definitely frustrating, you are right.

Comment: @ Did, perhaps you should read the rules of the site at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic where it specifically says we welcome questions about solving mathematical puzzles.

Comment: Sure we do, this is well known believe it or not, but even questions about puzzles should include some context. (Unrelated: Do you know the effect of inserting a space between the sign @ and a user's name?)