# Question Deleted After Receiving Answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deletion

This is another example of an OP deleting a question after receiving an answer.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3334999/find-a-jordan-basis-for-a-linear-operator

This has been discussed before: [Why do some users delete their questions after receiving an answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/why-do-some-users-delete-their-questions-after-receiving-an-answer).

However, I wonder if there is a way to add a feature to gray out the question and then allow users to flag it for a Moderator after the question is deleted because this is unfair to the person that posted an answer. Currently, all a user sees is Page Not Found and that makes it very difficult to take any action.

Lastly, should this question and answer be resurrected because of the unfairness?

**Update**

I see another (the same) question was just asked again: [Find a jordan basis for the given T linear operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335106/find-a-jordan-basis-for-the-given-t-linear-operator), as opposed to asking for clarification in the originally answered question.

Comment: I feel similarly about a question being closed and deleted after receiving highly-upvoted answers. Very frustrating.

Comment: Yes annoying, It happened that [i signaled a same problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365437/about-deleted-questions-already-answered) long time ago.

Comment: @TheCount yes, that is frustrating indeed. There is also a (new) [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97476/gentle) that tries to undo such things. Although you don't have enough reputation to cast undelete votes it might be really helpful if you link such posts there.

Comment: @Zacky Thanks for pointing that out. I proposed undeletion there. The question was not very good, but many of the answers (including, IMO, my own) were useful, I think.

Comment: +1 Glad to finally see a question about this. I feel this happens a lot on our site and needs to be addressed.

Comment: There are some older posts related to self-deleted after getting an answer. (Some for the above comments are more related to deletions in general rather than this particular type of deletion.) For example: [Why do some users delete their questions after receiving an answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8528) and [Is there need to patrol for deleted questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8540)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the current case: I merged the old version into the new one, thus preserving the initial answer.

It seems that the user asking, who is very new, reacted to feedback and did this rather well. Only, they deleted and reposted rather than editing. I explained them now how they should proceed.

---

For the general point, as you might know, for users with more than 10k+ this is in place already, they can see and flag deleted content. Your request seems to amount to lowering/abandoning the threshold for viewing deleted content. (Or do you have something more specific in mind?) I have mixed feelings about this, as deletion can also be useful. So, effectively abolishing it has some serious drawbacks.

If you happen to notice something like this you can always signal it in the dedicated thread on meta [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 07/2018 - today)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today) or also ask in chat in the [Math Mods' office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) or in [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude) for example.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback and it already sounds like there is a solution in place, so no action on that front.

Comment: quid, perhaps you should also mention that when posting on Math Mods' office, one should ping mods. Otherwise there is a high change of being ignored.

Comment: @Isa yes it can make sense to ping a pingable mod (I think usually I am pingable). That said, we do try to keep an eye on the room (even if we don't seem present), thus for the most part things don't get lost (I hope). But certainly everybody should feel free to ping.

Comment: really? I once posted there (without pings) and I was completely ignored by mods then. Only Martin replied to my request. And I think that was days later..

Comment: @Isa on the one hand, it was within about half a day, and you got to the point information. On the other hand, reconstructing from the date it seems you indeed had the misfortune to fall into my arguably least active week this year. Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh, I just checked again and  weren't days later but 15 hours later of Martin's response. Sorry.