# User keeps deleting most of the original text of the question after getting an answer

Tags: discussion, deletion

I would like to ask whether it is within the rules that a user keeps deleting most of the original text of a question after getting an answer. I have in mind for example these questions (of the same user and thus probably why I noticed it):

[Proving $f\in\mathbb{C}(D)$ if and only if for every closed set $F\subseteq R^m$, $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed (relatively) in $D$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3636458/proving-f-in-mathbbcd-if-and-only-if-for-every-closed-set-f-subseteq-rm)

[Prove $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists iff for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ s.t. for all $x_1,\,x_2\in D\cap (B(a,\delta)\setminus\{a\})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625067/prove-lim-x-to-afx-exists-iff-for-every-epsilon0-there-exists-a-del)

[Prove $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ and there exists a $\delta>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622661/prove-lim-x-to-afx-exists-if-and-only-if-for-every-epsilon0-and-there)

My guess is that this is a way of trying to hide getting help with homework. I caught some students of mine in such a situation in the site, but from the topics this should not be my student.

Really it is a pity that the answers in these (and other) questions are of less help for others since the questions are not there, only the answers.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, @John.  For the time being, until a moderator can deal with this, I have rolled back all their edits of the posts you mentioned, to fully reinstate the questions in their fullest form.  Probably, flagging any one of the posts, and linking others you noticed, for moderator attention would be just as effective as posting here.  But it is good to bring this up, here, or in a flag, so mods can address the user's behavior.

Comment: Same asker did so here, too: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3625322/revisions

Comment: And here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625322/proving-that-the-lim-x-to-0-fx-0 (rolled back by another user).

Comment: They seem to begin the majority of their posts as follows: "Can I please receive feedback on my proof/solution below? Thank you."

Comment: And here: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3609567/revisions (note deleted text of question.)

Comment: The problem has come up (not necessarily with the same user) more than once before. See, e.g., https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30612/question-deleted-after-receiving-answer and questions linked there.

Comment: So the student deleted most of his/her attempt at an answer to try to obfuscate that s/he got it checked by someone? Is that what’s going on?

Comment: I have seen this behavior recently : https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3617537/revisions The user is same as in other linked questions. Also you can see the audacity of the asker involved as he undoes twice the rollbacks which I and "user21820" did. I don't think there is harm in asking for help for homework question provided the user shows sufficient effort. I don't know if the professors would deduct credit for this (people in academic profession can throw more light on this).

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish: My best guess is that the intention here is to hide the fact that some outside help was used to solve homework/assignment problems . In my view whether an instructor punishes such behavior or not the damage is anyway done to the student as he/she does not learn. Knowledge is not only for grades but primarily for enjoyment and secondarily for applying in your life.

Comment: I think this a reasonably common (bad) behavior - I just rollback such edits and leave a comment and, if the user has done it more than once (or rolls my rollback back), I flag it - and I've always found the moderators respond well to this particular issue.

Comment: I am curious how editing the question hides possible help with answering the question? Does the instructor look at the answer on MSE? How would the instructor even know?