# How do I bring the attention towards a removed post? (I want to flag it for moderator attention)

Tags: support, flagging, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Just around 17 minutes ago, a question to which I have posted an answer got removed. I have seen this problem on meta somewhere where a solution was provided: flag the post for moderator attention and explain the problem in detail. The moderator might consider un-deleting it.
Now the problem is that I cannot see any option to flag the post. What can I do now?

I don't mind if the post isn't un-deleted. It was a fairly simple question. I just want to know what to do in such cases. I can use the information to proceed when a long/painstaking answer of mine ever gets deleted.

Here is the title of the question for reference:

> [How does $\ln y =\ln u+\ln k$ lead to $y=uk?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683636/how-does-lny-lnu-lnk-lead-to-y-uk)

Comment: For users with sufficient rep, [this is the post that was legitimately closed and deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683636/how-does-lny-lnu-lnk-lead-to-y-uk).  To request users to undelete or reopen a question, there is a dedicated thread, sai-kartik: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28692/9003.

Comment: Thank you @amWhy. This thread looks very useful. I shall definitely use it if any future answer of mine(long and painstaking as I have mentioned) gets deleted. However, I'm gonna let this question pass. It was too trivial anyway..

Comment: I should really get used to random downvotes on this site too....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you can flag *one of your own posts* for moderator attention, clearly indicating the flag is not about that post but the deleted one and you can't flag it in the regular way. You have 500 characters in the flag message so that *should* fit.

However, since you wrote an answer on that question, you can also find it back via the recently deleted answers list: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/736802 and (AFAIK) you can still flag the deleted question.

Comment: Yes this works. Thanks!

Comment: Heh, I was just editing that in. My solution would work if e.g. you were *typing* an answer but the question was deleted before you could submit it.

Comment: Yes. That's how I remember seeing the solution on meta here...

Comment: Status update: Flagged it

Comment: There is a dedicated meta-thread for [Requests to reopen or undelete posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28692/9003).  It is typically not appropriate to flag a mod to have a post reopened.  Maybe this is not true on SE in general, but then again: Some things are site-specific, Glorfindel.

Comment: @sai-kartik: you may also check the "U" in the [CURED chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/cured).

Comment: @T.S I'm sorry. What do you mean by "Check the 'U' " ?

Comment: The "U" stands for Undelete, meaning that you can request a post to be undeleted (but that doesn't mean it *will* be).

Comment: BTW, I'm **not** suggesting to flag a post for moderator attention to get it reopened, as we have a [community review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) for that. The author here is talking about drawing moderator attention to a *deleted* post, which as per [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8529/228959) is standard policy here as well at least in *some* cases. @amWhy I'll take your word for it that this particular deletion was warranted.

Comment: @Glorfindel The answer you link to is about a user deleting their *own* question, taking an answer with it. This question was deleted via a different process.

Comment: @user1729 fair enough; I can't check that. I assumed it was such a case and the author of this question had already decided wanting to flag for moderator attention. I'm merely telling them *how* to do that.

Comment: Also, Glorfindel, while the community review queue does review closed questions, when edited or when receiving a reopen vote, but it doesn't review deleted questions.